# KTable updates are not consistent when doing a join with a KStream

Tags: java, apache-kafka-streams

We are having an issue with a Kafka Streams Java application.
We have a KStream and a KTable which are joined using a Left Join. The entries in the KTable are constantly updated by the new information that comes from the KStream. Each KStream message is adding entries to an array that the KTable has for each key. This update gets sent back to the KTable topic, expanding this array every time a new message comes from the KStream.

As an example, what should be happening (and what happens in our unit tests) is:

- KTable has an empty array for key “foo”: []
- Event 1 comes with key “foo” and value “bar”
- Ktable gets updated to “foo”: [“bar”] , sending this update´to´ the same topic that the KTable is plugged into.
- Event 2 comes with key “foo” and value “baz”
- Update is pulled to mem by Ktable, and the Ktable gets updated to “foo”: [“bar, “baz”], sending this change ´to´ the same topic that the KTable is plugged into. Baz was appended to the array for key “foo”.

But what is happening is the following:

- KTable has an empty array for key “foo”: []
- Event 1 comes with key “foo” and value “bar”
- Ktable gets updated to “foo”: [“bar”] in the joiner, sending an event ´to´ the same topic that the KTable is plugged to.
- Event 2 comes with key “foo” and value “baz”
- Ktable gets updated to “foo”: [“baz”]  in the joiner, sending an event ´to´ the same topic that the KTable is plugged to afterwards.

This happens multiple times, and after a couple of seconds, one of the incoming messages is finally appended, but many of them are lost. As you can see, we suspect that when the Event 2 is received, the KTable has somehow not received  the first update for adding “baz” to the array.
This means that many events are missed, and we cannot successfully get the KTable to save all the data for all the events. In turn, it sometimes overwrites the updates from some events.

So far, we have tried:

- Setting STATESTORE_CACHE_MAX_BYTES_CONFIG to 0, to attempt to force the app not to cache any changes and send to the output topic instantly.
- Setting COMMIT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG to 0, to attempt to force the app to send all updates instantly
- Setting TOPOLOGY_OPTIMIZATION_CONFIG to “reuse.ktable.source.topics” and “all” in case there is some optimization pattern that could help us.

None of these have allowed us to have a fully consistent update of the KTable each time a new event comes. It always gets overwritten or misses incoming updates made by events.  Can someone advice if there’s a way to make the KTable get successfully updated by each one of the events, as the first example shows?

Most importantly, the tests that run this flow work differently compared to what happens when the app is really running.

Also, here’s an example topology where this is happening:

```
Sub-topology: 0
    Source: KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000000 (topics: [event-updates-topic])
      --> KSTREAM-MAPVALUES-0000000001
    Processor: KSTREAM-MAPVALUES-0000000001 (stores: [])
      --> KSTREAM-LEFTJOIN-0000000004
      <-- KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000000
    Processor: KSTREAM-LEFTJOIN-0000000004 (stores: [tableStateStore])
      --> KSTREAM-FILTER-0000000005
      <-- KSTREAM-MAPVALUES-0000000001
    Processor: KSTREAM-FILTER-0000000005 (stores: [])
      --> KSTREAM-MAPVALUES-0000000006
      <-- KSTREAM-LEFTJOIN-0000000004
    Processor: KSTREAM-MAPVALUES-0000000006 (stores: [])
      --> KSTREAM-SINK-0000000007
      <-- KSTREAM-FILTER-0000000005
    Source: KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000002 (topics: [saved-data])
      --> KTABLE-SOURCE-0000000003
    Sink: KSTREAM-SINK-0000000007 (topic: saved-data)
      <-- KSTREAM-MAPVALUES-0000000006
    Processor: KTABLE-SOURCE-0000000003 (stores: [tableStateStore])
      --> none
      <-- KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000002
```